# Prerender behaviour when redirect meta tag is set

Tags: single-page-application, prerender

I have an Angular SPA, with a particular page (Page A) which we want to temporarily redirect to another page (Page B).

We set the following headers so that Prerender detects the redirect:

```
<meta name="prerender-status-code" content="302">
<meta name="prerender-header" content="Location: Page B">
```

Is it important that the `prerenderReady` flag is set to true AFTER Page B is fully rendered? Or will Prerender then attempt to crawl Page B separately?